# SQL query / CTE for Association table having many to many relationships

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have two tables `A` and `B`. B can have many records of A but B will not have any records of A

One-to-many ->  one way

Now

Table **A**:

```
Id    Name 
----------    
1     Rule1
2     Rule2
```

Table **B**:

```
Id TargetedTypeId TargetedId  TargetingType TargetingId Status
```

**TargetedType** table:

```
Id   Name  
--------------
1    Users                          
2    Employee
```

**TargetingType** table:

```
Id   Name
-----------------
1    Vegetable  
2    Fruits
```

**Users** table:

```
Id   Name
--------------
1    Abc                             
2    xyz
```

**Vegetables** table:

```
Id    Name
-----------------
1     Onion                   
2     Potato
```

**Fruits** table:

```
Id    Name
---------------    
1     Apple
2     Orange
```

Table **B** will have rows like this:

```
Id | TargetedTypeId | TargetedId (Table A Ids) | TargetingType | TargetingId | Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1           1                 2            1               2             1
 2           1                 2            1               1             1
 3           1                 2            2               1             1
 4           1                 2            2               2             1
```

Please hep me to write a query which will fetch A tables entries present in B with status 1 and fetch all  targeting types and get fruit details if its fruit and if vegetable if its vegetable type which is TargetingType and fetch its details with respective table fruit/vegetable with Pagination

Comment: "B can have many records of A but B will not have any records of A "?: 0 or many?

Comment: B will have Many records Of A which is Targeted Ids IN Table B

Comment: Just don't get this question or latest comment reply. Use rextester and link example. Put data into some tables and describe desired output for specific set of data. id's just don't cut it.